Would you be interested in a weekly topic challenge?
Would you be interested in a weekly topic challenge?
What is it?  Basically, every week we choose a topic to focus on and everyone tries to pitch in by asking a question on that topic.  See this SO blog post about it:

The Jewish Life and Learning community employs a unique means of encouraging a stream of new topics: their weekly topic challenge. It’s simple, yet effective: users propose topics on meta, which are voted up or down based on what other users would like to answer, and the week’s topic is announced through a separate meta thread every week.
Choosing a new theme each week is a tactic that works. I know that, personally, there are sites where I’d love to contribute more, but sometimes coming up with a question can be tough. These topic prompts can break this writer’s block and nudge users into articulating what it is they want to ask. Trying to come up with a single question among the many possibilities of a site’s scope is overwhelming sometimes.

Just a few suggestions for what our topics could be:

Asset Allocation
Algorithmic Trading
Options Theory

Pretty much any of our major tags could be a "topic" for the weekly challenge.  If you like this idea and you think you would participate, then up-vote this post.  If you have specific recommendations or suggestions for topics, please submit them below and we can vote on them as a group.
UPDATE: I think I will do it, but starting early next year to avoid the year-end lull in traffic. Please add more of your topic suggestions for future weeks.

Sounds great! I second that this can work.

agreed...........

Yep great idea.

Great idea.....

Asset allocation 
Asset allocation is a deep and wide topic that has not seen much activity yet.

Your list is a great starting point.
A few more:

Money management
Risk management (e.g. VaR)
Optimization methods
Transaction Cost Analysis
Anomalies (e.g. momentum)
Market microstructure theory (e.g. order book dynamics)
Other derivatives (swaps, swaptions, ...)

